# How to assert that a JSON contains certain keys?

Tags: javascript, json, cypress, chai, assertion

I have successfully converted an excel sheet's content into a JSON, now I am trying to do some validation to it.

I need to assert that the `jsonData` below contains the following keys: `Breakfast`, `Lunch`, `Snack`, `Dinner`. It should also be in this specific order.

To test out an assertion first, I tried this:

```
const jsonData = [{  
  "Breakfast": "Cereal",
  "Lunch": "Chicken",
  "Snack": "Biscuit",
  "Dinner": "Pork",
  "Drinks": "Water"
}]

expect(jsonData).to.be.an('array').that.contains.keys('Breakfast')
```

And I got this error:
[image: AssertionError: expected [ Array(1) ] to contain key 'Breakfast']

Comment: Are you sure you want to have an array with only 1 object in it? An array has only numeric keys. The assertion should be that `jsonData` is an array and that `jsonData[0]` contains keys, or that all elements in `jsonData` contain your keys, depending on your specification.

Comment: So, FWIW, this in Object, not JSON; JSON is a string. You can use `jsonData.hasOwnProperty("Breakfast")` or `Object.keys(jsonData).includes("Breakfast")`. However Objects don't keep any particular. If you need them to be in a certain order, I would use a `Map()` instead.

Comment: @user1599011 - So I tried `expect(jsonData).to.haveOwnProperty("Breakfast")` and it fails, giving me the same Assertion Error. Also tried `expect(Object.keys(jsonData).includes("Breakfast")).to.be.true` and an Assertion Error says "expected false to be true". I am not sure if I am doing the correct way of assertion for this.

Comment: @ggorlen - it doesn't have to be an Array. I just tried out `to.be.an('array')` as I was searching about Assertions. I need to come up with the right assertion to check that those keys are in the JSON.

Comment: Please re-read my comment. Your assertions still don't make sense. Assert that objects have certain keys, not the `jsonData` array. `Object.keys(jsonData)` doesn't make sense because that just retuns a bunch of numbers--the array keys. Try printing your intermediate values to make sure they look like you expect.

Comment: My bad. I have now realized that I should have used `jsonData[0]`, because I've enclosed the `jsonData` in `[ ]`. This assertion works for me: `expect(jsonData[0]).to.contain.keys('Breakfast')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone's inputs have been such a big help. This is what I have come up with, let me know if there are ways to improve or if there are better ways to do this.

```
// This points to my testdata.json file
const column = testdata.Meals.column

const key = Object.keys(jsonData[0])
const value = Object.values(jsonData[0])

const jsonData = [{
  "Breakfast": "Cereal",
  "Lunch": "Chicken",
  "Snack": "Biscuit",
  "Dinner": "Pork",
  "Drinks": "Water"
  "Something": "Else"
}]

cy.wrap(column).each(($el, index, $list) => {
  expect(jsonData[0]).to.haveOwnProperty(key[index])

  // To check the specific order of the key-value pair
  if (index == 0) {
    expect(key[i]).to.eql(column[index])
    expect(value[index]).to.eql(context.mealName)
  } else if (index == 2) {
    expect(key[index]).to.eql(column[index])
    expect(value[index]).to.eql(context.snackName)
  } else if (index == 4) {
    expect(key[index]).to.eql(column[index])
    expect(value[index]).to.eql(context.drinkName)
  }
})
```

The `testdata.js` file:

```
{
 "Meals": {
  "column": [
    "Breakfast",
    "Lunch",
    "Snack",
    "Dinner",
    "Drinks"
  ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would say `to.contain.keys` can't be applied to the array, but only the first object within the array.

Try splitting out that first item.

```js
const jsonData = [{  
  "Breakfast": "Cereal",
  "Lunch": "Chicken",
  "Snack": "Biscuit",
  "Dinner": "Pork",
  "Drinks": "Water"
}]

expect(jsonData).to.be.an('array')

const firstItem = jsonData[0]
expect(firstItem).to.contain.keys('Breakfast')
```

---

**Syntax for chai keys assertion**

Reading the [docs](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_keys), I'm not sure `to.contain.keys` is correct syntax either.

Try

```js
expect(firstItem).to.include.any.keys('Breakfast')
```

---

**Simplest method**

You can assert that "Breakfast" exists by comparing it to `undefined`

First object:

```js
expect(jsonData[0].Breakfast).to.not.eq(undefined)
```

Every object in the array

```js
jsonData.forEach(item => {
  expect(item.Breakfast).to.not.eq(undefined)
}
```